# PHP - Post data Form with json to Google Docs

Tags: php, json, google-docs

In my country some Sites are filtered, for example `docs.google.com`, `bbc.co.uk`, `facebook` etc.

I create a `Form` in google docs. When I embed form with `iframe` in my site, users from my country can't view `From`.

For this reason, I get source HTML `google form` and then insert to my site. Now users from my country can view the form but when they click `Submit`, data form can't be sent to google docs, becase google docs url is filtered! My server site is in USA.

Can I get data form from users and then send form with server (with POST method) to google docs?

For example my form code is this:

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1B_p03NcbwnGRFAiAy0YoEPFckDELH1I-p71_2Kgq6_A/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit="">
    Your Name: <input type="text" name="entry.278240263" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_278240263" dir="auto" aria-required="true" required="" title="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" id="ss-submit">
</form>
```

I need to send data form to `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1B_p03NcbwnGRFAiAy0YoEPFckDELH1I-p71_2Kgq6_A/formResponse` with server by Json

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Have a look at: https://wiki.base22.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72942000
There is a section describing how to post data to google docs by ajax from javascript but it should be similar in php